# Outlook Reading Pane loses settings on app close

Tags: microsoft-outlook

My Reading Pane options within Outlook 2016/2019 refuse to stay saved, hiding the selected message from the Reading Pane by default.

[image]

How can I make my settings persist on app close and re-open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there is a [known issue](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10-mso_2019/reading-pane-issues-outlook-2019/42cecca6-2c55-4ad6-b83d-30873f317753) causing this as of April 2021.

Uncheck "Store settings in the cloud" within File > Options:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Before going further, just make sure that you have upgraded your Outlook to the latest version.

As I know, you could check your Registry settings and set the Reading Pane settings using `previewmarkmessage` and `previewwaitseconds` keys.

[image]

For more information:

[Outlook Reading Pane loses settings on app close](https://superuser.com/questions/1650781/outlook-reading-pane-loses-settings-on-app-close).

[Backup and restore Outlook settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/395803/backup-and-restore-outlook-settings.html)